# Como obtener la hora del servidor con node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

La manera que lo hago con javascript del lado del cliente es la siguiente

```
function srvTime(){
     try {

         xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     catch (err1) {
         //IE
         try {
             xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
         }
         catch (err2) {
             try {
                 xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
             }
             catch (eerr3) {
                 alert("AJAX not supported");
             }
         }
     }
     xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
     xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
     xmlHttp.send('');
     return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
 }
```

Sin embargo con node.js no puedo ya que no me detecta la libreria de XMLHttpRequest y marca window como indefinido.

De que forma lo pudiera hacer con node

Nota: Necesito la del servidor al que estoy conectada no la del dispositivo.

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener la hora del servidor con node simplemente colocas:

```
var fecha= new Date();
var hora_actual = fecha.getHours();
```

ó

```
var fecha = Date.now();
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias pero como dije en mi post, busco como obtener la hora del servidor al que esta mi aplicacion conectada no del dispositivo en la que esta siendo usada.

Comment: con eso lo puedes hacer, ese còdigo va del lado del servidor y se lo retornarias al cliente

Comment: creo que no me estas comprendiendo, no me refiero a servidor como back-end. si no que literal la aplicacion obtine informacion de un servidor en especifico. Ejemplo en mi pc accedo a la aplicacion que esta montada en el servidor 10.10.1.101, y mi pc tiene la ip 10.10.1.133, yo necesito la hora del 10.10.1.101 no del 133 que es mi pc. Usando solo Date.now() regresa la fecha de mi pc.

Comment: Yo estoy hablando del lado del servidor, ese código lo ejecutas del lado del servidor no del cliente, por eso si lo ejecutas del lado del cliente te sale la hora tuya y no del servidor, el código que  te di va del lado del servidor con node

Comment: Estoy preguntandolo porque aunque tengo el metodo del lado del servidor me sigue dando la hora del cliente

Comment: Ok que código tienes del lado del servidor? es que todo lo que indicas es dle lado del cliente, si puedes editar y agregar lo que haz hecho del lado del servidor seria de utilidad

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices la dependencia `moment`, la cual te permite manejar fechas y horas de una forma muy sencilla.

Para incorporar `moment` a tu proyecto, deberás ejecutar el comando `npm i --save moment`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
const moment = require('moment')

let currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

let currentTime = moment().format('hh:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

Y si se quiere obtener la hora en su pais de origen
R://

```
    const dateformat = require('dateformat');
const nDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Lima'});
let time= dateformat(nDate, "HH:MM");
console. log(time);
```